# How to parellize a PDF generation in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have a function that effectively does this ->

for each content :
  wkhtmlcreatepdf(content)

content can be 10 big records for example .

I need to parellize this process instaed of waiting for each to complete . Is it possible ?

Comment: Have you tried to use python threads?? some examples can be found here: http://www.wellho.net/solutions/python-python-threads-a-first-example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is possible. You just need to use this:

http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html

or this:

http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html

Note that if the number of jobs is really big, then creating thread/process for each may even crash your OS (and at least there will be no advantage in using like 100 threads). Thus additionally you should use thread/process pools. For example see this:

http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers